# Noisy kitchen vent fan

Tags: range, venting

My kitchen vent is a 6" duct that curves to the side, goes to the outside wall, where a fan is mounted, pulling the air outside. Due to the curve (and the fan, I think), when I turn on the fan, it sounds like a jet engine is taking off... both due to "air whooshing" around the bend and the noise of the fan itself.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the noise? Specifically I'm curious if there is any lining I can use in the vent, or a cover that muffles the sound a bit. Or maybe a quieter fan?

[image: duct]

Comment: You can add insulation but first I would ask what kind of duct? If flex change to smooth ridgid and insulate will quiet things down for exhaust fan I have found the quiet ones don’t stay that way once some grease builds up on them.

Comment: I've added a photo. I'm not sure what types of ducts there are, but mine does curve

Comment: That is ridgid, is the back draft damper (flap opening) sometimes they get sticky with grease and when the fan can’t push any air they spin up really fast because the load on the fan is moving the air.

Comment: Try removing the fan, lubricating the motor and cleaning the blade.

Comment: While you have it out, you might see if you can find a quieter replacement fan. It looks like the fan may have been in service for quite a while. There may be more quiet, more efficient models available cheap.

Comment: Thanks all. Very much appreciated.

Comment: might hot glue or rubber cement the seams of the metal duct, and the grate itself. I had a fan in an old apt where the segments slightly rattled and once glued, the loudest part of the equation was the rusty fan itself, which oiling the motor and cleaning the blades further reduced.